# how can i get data from view

Tags: c#, wpf

i use MVVM to built my project, now i have some troubles,when i click a button,  i want get data from view to viewmodel, what should i do?

thanks
Bob

Answer (score 2):

Bind that data to the view model and execute a command when the user clicks the button. The command and data are housed in the view model, so it has everything it needs.

```
public class YourViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private readonly ICommand doSomethingCommand;
    private string data;

    public YourViewModel()
    {
        this.doSomethingCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.DoSomethingWithData);
    }

    public ICommand DoSomethingCommand
    {
        get { return this.doSomethingCommand; }
    }

    public string Data
    {
        get { return this.data; }
        set
        {
            if (this.data != value)
            {
                this.data = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged(() => this.Data);
            }
        }
    }

    private void DoSomethingWithData(object state)
    {
        // do something with data here
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Data}"/>
<Button Command="{Binding DoSomethingWithData}"/>
```

For information on the various dependencies in the above example such as `ViewModel` and `DelegateCommand`, see my [series of posts on MVVM](http://kentb.blogspot.com/search/label/MVVM).

EDIT after receiving more info: For tracking item selection, simply introduce a view model to represent the item:

```
public class CustomerViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private bool isSelected;

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return this.isSelected; }
        set
        {
             if (this.isSelected != value)
             {
                 this.isSelected = value;
                 this.OnPropertyChanged(() => this.IsSelected);
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Your "main" view model would expose a collection of these items (generally an `ObservableCollection<T>`):

```
public ICollection<CustomerViewModel> Customers
{
    get { return this.customers; }
}
```

Your view would then bind as:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Notice how each `ListBoxItem` will have its IsSelected property bound to the `CustomerViewModel.IsSelected` property. Thus, your main view model can just check this property to determine which customers are selected:

```
var selectedCustomers = this.Customers.Where(x => x.IsSelected);
```

Comment: hi kent：
maybe my describe is not so familiar with my current problem,
in my view i have a listbox and i select some of the items in this
listbox then i click a button  ,i want the viewmodel get the select items what should i do?

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The solution suggested by Kent is in my opinion by far the best/only one to follow MVVM.
If however you don't want to replicate/reflect listbox selections to the view model or you want a quick and - according to MVVM - dirty solution, you can use the command parameter to send data from the view to the view model.

For that you have to bind the `CommandParameter` property of the button to the property which contains the data you want to send to the view model. For simplicity I just used a `TextBox`.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBox x:Name="Data"/>
    <Button Content="DoSomething" 
            Command="{Binding Path=DoSomethingCommand}" 
            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Data, Path=Text}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The ViewModel of the sample looks like the following.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private ICommand doSomethingCommand = new MyCommand();

    public ICommand DoSomethingCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return doSomethingCommand;
        }
    }
}
```

With this, you will get the specified content as the parameter in the `Execute` method of `ICommand`.

```
public class MyCommand : ICommand
{
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        string dataFromView = (string)parameter;

        // ...
        MessageBox.Show(dataFromView);
    }
}
```